# How to show an image stream (cgi) which is secured by http authentication

Tags: php, html, image, cgi

How can I show an image stream from a cheap camera with standard HTTP protection without showing the authentication window?

It's a standard HTML image stream:

```
<img src="http://192.168.1.96/mjpeg.cgi">
```

but because the image is protected it won't load it's just gives a http 401. I do have the login data, but how can I show the image stream?

PS.:
I tried using PHP curl, but because this is a continuous image stream that didn't work, it just filled my memory.